# Segmentation fault 11 error while reading file into dynamic array

Tags: c, file

I am trying to read a file that can be empty or can contain numbers into a dynamic array. And I am getting  segmentation fault after it reads all the numbers in the file, or the file is empty and I am not sure why, it is doing that.

```
    //ptr and fp are passed from another function
ptr = malloc(10 * sizeof(int)); 
if (ptr == NULL){
    printf("failed to allocate memory\n");
}
int sz = 10;
int counter = 0;
int fnum;
int *temp;
char lp1[MAXLINE];// maxline is 100
int i = 0;
while(fgets(lp1, MAXLINE, fp)!= NULL){
    if(counter >= sz){
        sz *=2;
        temp = realloc(ptr,sz);
        if (temp == NULL) {
            printf("failed to allocate memory\n");
        }
        if (temp != NULL){
            ptr = temp;
            //free(temp);
        }
    }
    int len = strlen(lp1);
    if (len > 0 && lp1[len-1] == '\n'){
        lp1[len-1] = 0;
    }
    fnum = strToInt(lp1);// number from file
    printf("%i value of lp1 \n", fnum);
    ptr[i] = fnum;
    i++;
    counter++;
}
return sz;
```

Comment: That outcommented `free` call after your reallocation, remove the line completely.

Comment: Also, why are you using two variables (`i` and `counter`) that will be the same values? Use one or the other. as both index and the current "size".

Comment: //free(temp); is inside the comment , but I removed it and tried running it again and I am still getting segmentation fault.

Comment: The commented call have nothing to do with the problem, remember that comments will just be discarded by the compiler. But you will get problem if you remove the comment and have the `free` call, remember that at that point you have two pointers both pointing to the same memory. Freeing one will free that memory, making the other pointer invalid.

Comment: `strToInt` might have a bug. Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Your first `realloc` call will *shrink* the allocated memory from (probably) 40 bytes to 20 bytes. The size provided is in *bytes* and not the number of "elements". You need to multiply with the base "element" size here too.

---

Also, if `ptr` is passed as an argument, then you're doing *pass by reference* wrong. First of all, C doesn't have pass by reference, only *pass by value* meaning your function gets a *copy* of the current value of the variable you pass as argument. This *copy* is stored in the *local variable* `ptr`, and like all other local variables it will go out of scope once the function returns, and all changes to it will be lost.

To fix this you need to *emulate* pass by value by passing a pointer to the variable, like e.g.

```
// Code calling your function
...
int *ptr;
you_function(..., &ptr, ...);  // Use address-of operator to pass pointer to variable
...

// Your function
int your_function(..., int **pptr, ...)
{
    ...
    *pptr = malloc(...);  // Use dereference operator to access what pptr points to
    ...
    // Use parenthesis because array indexing have higher precedence than dereference
    (*pptr)[counter++] = (int) strtol(lp1, NULL, 10);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I fixed the realloc to temp = realloc(ptr,sz* sizeof(int)); But I a still getting the error

Comment: @Gkush Please read my answer again, especially the added section. And learn how to use a debugger so you can find the crashes yourself, and locate them in your source, and step through the code while monitoring variables and their values.

Answer (score 0):

I believe multiplying by 2 makes the required memory grow exponentially, until it is bigger than the memory your system can allocate. Get the size of the file beforehand and then allocate memory for it. Make sure you release it when you don't need it anymore.

Other thing I recommend you, stop storing numbers on files. Instead create a sqlite database and do it properly. Will save you nightmares and headaches.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple example that can give you the idea. Have a file and a program, read the file and scan the tokens.

**sample.txt**

> 0 1 23 2134   123 12321
>
> 123
>
> 42

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen("sample.txt", "r");
    int x;
    while (fscanf(fp, " %d", &x) == 1) { }
    printf("Last integer is %d.\n", x);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Output

```
$ ./a.out 
Last integer is 42.
```

Comment: Please read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). This also doesn't answer the question about the crashes.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I improved my answer a little, will you have a look again? Didn't know that C had so many mistakes.